# how to give style dynamically to template via angular part?

Tags: css, angular

My HTML part is:

```
<li *ngIf="action==null" id="list_icon"><a href="#" id="anchor"><i class={{icon}}></i> {{name}} {{color}}</a></li>
        <li *ngIf="action!=null" id="list_icon" class="active"><span id="anchor"><i class={{icon}}></i> {{name}}</span></li>
```

and css is :

```
li a{
  background-color: red !important;
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}

li a:before{
border-left-color: red !important;
}
```

Now my question is, I want to use the color in Css as shown below:

```
li a{background-color: {{color}} !important;}
```

and my {{color}} data is coming from my controller or class. the {{color}} is displayed on template but wont work in my style. is there any other method to give style dynamically via angular data. or there need some correction in my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem itself. following are some steps that i have done.

1. import `NgClass` directive from angular2/angular2.
2. add `NgClass` as directive in the @view annotations.
3. add `[ng-class]="color"` to the HTML part.
4. add color class to the style.

Done.

*Important

angular2 provides ngClass built in directive for styling document. for more help you can read the whole tutorial here https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/NgClass-class.html .

## --update--

as of angular2 beta0.0

1. ng-class is updated to ngClass
2. ngClass is imported from angular2/common.
3. ng-style is updated to [ngStyle].

Answer (score 5):

With Angular2 you can update the background-color attribute directly like this:
`[style.background]="color"`

so you can change your `<a>` to this:
`<a href="#" id="anchor" [style.background]="color">`

Comment: this is working but i m looking for something else like ngClass. by the way thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please try with `ngStyle`. You can set the style in the following way:

```
<a ng-style="{'background-color': color}">Sample Text</a>
```

For more please check the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for each color and use those:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/293302t5/1/)

HTML:

```
<li id="list_icon"><a href="#" id="anchor" ng-class="color"><i class={{icon}}></i> {{name}} {{color}}</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
.green {
    background-color: green !important;
    border: 1px solid green !important;
}
```

JS:

```
app.controller('dummy', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.color = 'green';
}]);
```

Comment: yes exactly but i want ngClass for angular2. i have already post the answer thanks.